# Replace all elements with certain class

Tags: javascript

If a user is browsing on a phone, I am trying to replace all `div` elements with class `'section-heading'` with a `button`. The code I wrote only replaces the first instance of a `div` with said class but leaves the remaining ones:

```
  sectionHeadings = document.getElementsByClassName("section-heading");
  for(i = 0; i < sectionHeadings.length; i++){
    divToReplace = sectionHeadings[i]; 
    btn = document.createElement('button');
    btnText = sectionHeadings[i].innerHTML;
    btn.innerHTML = btnText;
    divToReplace.parentNode.replaceChild(btn, divToReplace);
  }
```

snippet of html:

```
<div class="section-heading" id="appetizers">Appetizers</div>
<div class="section-heading" id="soups">Soups</div>
```

Not sure why my loop is only replacing the first element with a `button`, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place? Can't you use media queries? I can't imagine any possible use case where replacing divs with buttons would really work in favor of CSS.

Comment: @matweka this a serious question... I can do that with media queries? I thought I could only change style attributes.

Comment: @matewka because you are correct that would make this much simpler

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some issues with your code, and now it works (:

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("section-heading")].forEach((h) => {
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    const btnText = h.innerHTML;
    btn.innerHTML = btnText;
    h.parentNode.replaceChild(btn, h);
});
```

```html
<div class="section-heading" id="appetizers">Appetizers</div>
<div class="section-heading" id="soups">Soups</div>
```

The main thing you should note is that not initializing your variables explicitly, you create global variables.

But the main reason it didn't work, is as junvar pointed out, that you were dealing with a *live* `nodeList`.

Comment: that's awesome... I also did not know this forEach method existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
sectionHeadings = document.getElementsByClassName("section-heading");
[...sectionHeadings].forEach((elem)=>{
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML;
  elem.outerHTML = btn.outerHTML ; 
});
```

```html
<div class="section-heading" id="appetizers">Appetizers</div>
<div class="section-heading" id="soups">Soups</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getElementsByClassName` returns a live list; i.e. it updates when the elements change. In your case, you're replacing a `.section-heading` element with a button that doesn't have the class `.section-heading`, so you're reducing the length of `sectionHeadings` by 1 each iteration. You can see this by adding a `console.log(sectionHeadings)` after the `replaceChild` call.

The simple solution is to convert `secxtionHeadings` to a non-live array by using the spread operator.

```js
let sectionHeadings = [...document.getElementsByClassName("section-heading")];
for (i = 0; i < sectionHeadings.length; i++) {
  divToReplace = sectionHeadings[i];
  btn = document.createElement('button');
  // btn.classList.add('section-heading'); // This would also solve the issue, but could have unintended side-effects.
  btnText = sectionHeadings[i].innerHTML;
  btn.innerHTML = btnText;
  divToReplace.parentNode.replaceChild(btn, divToReplace);
  console.log(i, sectionHeadings.length, sectionHeadings)
}
```

```html
<div class="section-heading" id="appetizers">Appetizers</div>
<div class="section-heading" id="soups">Soups</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method returns a [live `HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). The collection reflects the current status of the elements on the page, and changes automatically when elements with the class are added or removed. When you replace the 1st `div` with a `button`, you remove an element with the class `.section-heading`, and the next item becomes the 1st, but since the loop already handled the 1st item (`i = 0`) it will be skipped.

Instead of using a method which returns a live collection, use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which produces a static [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Then use [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) to iterate the list of nodes, and replace them:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.section-heading')
  .forEach(divToReplace => {
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.innerHTML = divToReplace.innerHTML;
    divToReplace.parentNode.replaceChild(btn, divToReplace);
  })
```

```html
<div class="section-heading" id="appetizers">Appetizers</div>
<div class="section-heading" id="soups">Soups</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `getElementsByClassName` returns a live list that will be updated I think you just need to replace always the first element of this list something like this

```
  sectionHeadings = document.getElementsByClassName("section-heading");
  while(sectionHeadings.length > 0){
    divToReplace = sectionHeadings[0]; 
    btn = document.createElement('button');
    btnText = sectionHeadings[0].innerHTML;
    btn.innerHTML = btnText;
    divToReplace.parentNode.replaceChild(btn, divToReplace);
  }
```

```
<div class="section-heading" id="appetizers">Appetizers</div>
<div class="section-heading" id="soups">Soups</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('section-heading')].forEach(divToReplace => {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = divToReplace.innerHTML;
  divToReplace.replaceWith(btn);
});
```

1. Converting nodeList to and array -
   [...document.getElementsByClassName('section-heading')]
2. forEach(divToReplace - looping throw each item
3. divToReplace.replaceWith(btn); - replacing current array item with btn

This solution is better because it doesn't need to traverse DOM to find parent and children.